# Using fget and parsing

Tags: c, parsing, io, stack

So I want to read a file, and i should have 4 functions:
it is the main function

```
/* Queue functions */

/* Basic type for the queue data structure */
typedef struct queue {
  node *front;          /* Front of the line */
  node *rear;   

    /* Back of the line */
} queue;
```

---

Sorry, I compiled wrongly, it works now.

Comment: Why did you edit out almost everything from this question? As it is now, there is no question. If you want to remove the question, then simply click on the delete link instead of editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `str2card` and `card2str` the prototype and the actual function differ.  They must be the same.  Probably the same with the other too.

You have prototypes here:

```
// Utility functions
node_data str2card(char *buf);
char *card2str(node_data c, char *buf);
```

and later the functions:

```
/* Convert a string like 14D into a card */
card str2card(char *buf){
...
}
...
/* Given a card c, put a string like 14D in buf representing it.  Good
for printing  */
char *card2str(card c, char *buf){
...
}
```